# Connecting IntelliJ Idea Servers to GitLab.com: what info is actually needed?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, gitlab, gitlab-api, intellij-17

I'm trying to configure IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.2 in order to [get the tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/tasks.html) from a private repository on GitLab.com.

To do that I have to create the corresponding [entry in the *Servers* window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/servers-2.html).

Now, I don't have the faintest idea about how I should fill the *Servers* form in IDEA.

What URL I have to use for *Server URL* ?
What token ?

[image]

Any advice? Thx in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

UPDATE: Based on the information mentioned in the issue [IDEA-193736](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-193736), the connectivity problem with the new GitLab Issues API (V4) should be fixed when the update 2018.2 is released.

The https://gitlab.com URL didn't work for me as the API URL was updated to V4 on GitLab. So, after some trial and error I was able to make it work by completing the following steps:

1. Create a Personal Access Token on GitLab (https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) with API and read_user access permissions
2. In IntelliJ (or Pycharm in my case), the Server URL should be https://gitlab.com/api/v4/issues? (with the question mark at the end)
3. The token is the Personal Access Token that was generated previously

Also, don't forget to increase the connection timeout to 15000 milliseconds under the Tasks section in the Settings (Settings => Tools => Tasks).

[Task Server Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5smT3.png)

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Only problem is that I'm not being able to select the project, the dropdown just won't come down.

Comment: @CristianGomez By default, you will see all the tasks in all your projects. But, based on the [GitLab Issues API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html) information, you can apply a filter to only show a subset of tasks.

Comment: Mmn didn't try that, thanks, btw just to confirm, the plug-in by now it's abandoned/ not maintained anymore ?

Comment: @CristianGomez AFAIK it looks like it's still supported by Jetbrains as it's still included in the [help documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tutorial-configuring-generic-task-server.html), but they might not have updated that component recently

Comment: THANKS. This information cannot be found on the jetbrains docs. It's currently bundled with phpstorm btw

Comment: in order to get the issues of a concrete project use url: `http://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/123/issues?` where `123` is the ID of your project.

Answer (score 4):

[EDIT] This answer was valid in '17, when it was created. For an up to date anwer, pls see other answers in the thread.

So, here's how to do it.

1. First of all, go to [gitlab](https://gitlab.com).
2. Access with your data and get a personal *access token*.
   [image]
3. Then, you can configure IntelliJ Idea with the following values: [image]
4. You can now check all your GitLab's issues directly in Idea, as shown here below.[image]

Comment: in the current webstorm-version(July 2018), this gives me a "Not Found" - whereas the  https://<gitlab-server>/api/v4/issues? url gives me all the tasks, but from here I cannot select a project. Any idea how I can get both access and limit tasks to a project?